# Persistent Sessions on Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-dynamodb

I deployed my application on Amazon Beanstalk and the good news is that it works fine.

I am currently using the auto scaling feature and using sticky session with it.

My question is :

1. Can i somehow configure the Amazon Beanstalk to store all my session information in RDS or Dynamo DB.
2. My constraint is that i cannot develop a new application from ground up fully using RDS as it is a mature application and above approach is not feasible.
3. Also let's say we are somehow able to store sessions in Dynamo
   DB,how do i see the contents of this database,is there a way on AWS
   console.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check this doc for configuring session state in Tomcat. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-tomcat-session-manager.html

A blog post on how you can deploy this on Elastic Beanstalk: http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx12CFK2FZ7PXRN/Amazon-DynamoDB-Session-Manager-for-Apache-Tomcat

Hope this helps,
Swami